# "argument "name" is missing with no default" (R error)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, dashboard

I am learning about dashboards using the R package "flexdashboards". I am trying to follow the tutorial listed over here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/

I tried to copy the first line of code from this website to open the "dashboard template editor":

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(rmarkdown)
library(rbokeh)
library(knitr)

rmarkdown::draft("dashboard.Rmd", template = "flex_dashboard", package = "flexdashboard")
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Error in editor(file = file, title = title) : argument "name" is missing with no default
```

Does anyone know why this error is appearing? Based on the instructions from the website (https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/), after entering this code a popup window should appear?

Thanks

UPDATE: as per the suggestion of @Ronald, I added a "traceback" option

```
options(error = traceback)

rmarkdown::draft("dashboard.Rmd", template = "flex_dashboard", package = "flexdashboard")

Error in editor(file = file, title = title): argument "name" is missing, with no default

3: editor(file=file, title = title)
2: utils::file.edit(normalizePath(file))
1: rmarkdown::draft("dashboard.Rmd", template = "flex_dashboard", package = "flexdashboard")
```

Comment: This works fine on my system (I only loaded the first two packages). Please provide at least the output of `traceback()` after the error occurred and indicate which OS your are on.

Comment: thank you for your reply! this is my first time hearing about traceback() . Do you mean like this : options(error = traceback)?

Comment: @Roland : please see the updates made to the question. I using R version 3.4.1. on windows >=8

Comment: What does `getOption("editor")` return for you? Note that version 3.4.1 of R is pretty old (it was released in 2017). Are you using RStudio or just the regular R GUI?

Comment: Before you spend more time on this, I strongly encourage you to update R.

Comment: @MrFlick : please see the updates, i included the output of "getOption". I am using R studio .

Comment: Ok. That looks like an RStudio problem them. I'm using RStudio 1.3 and I see the `getOption("editor")` function has an explicit test for `if (missing(name)) `. The version you are running does not have that. This looks like a bug that was fixed in 2018: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3475

Comment: Thank you! Do you think if i copy the correct defintion of this function it might work?

Comment: What version of RStudio are you currently using? I'm guessing it won't work because the APIs have probably changed but I guess you could try.

Comment: I guess the better option would be to update R?